# Modify document position in collection using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection of `vouchers`. The user can add a `voucher` and then order them in the front part.

My goal is to re-order all documents in `vouchers` collection in terms of how the user orders the list in the front.

Here is an example:
This is the current list

```
[
   {
     title: "one",
     id: "1",
   },
     {
     title: "two",
     id: "2",
   },
   {
     title: "three",
     id: "3",
   },
   {
     title: "four",
     id: "4",
   }
]
```

The user can re-order the list as follow:

```
[
    {
      title: "one",
      id: "1",
    },
    {
      title: "three",
      id: "3",
    },
      {
      title: "two",
      id: "2",
    },
    {
      title: "four",
      id: "4",
    }
]
```

And my main goal is to manage to re-order all the documents in the db as the second array example - where each object is a document.

I can maybe set a `index` field in the `voucher` schema, in a first query, set the position of the target element and then, in a second query, check the case where a document validate this condition :
`oldTargetElementIndex > otherElementIndex > currentTargetElementIndex` . If the document validate this condition, so I increment `index` by `1`.

It could be a solution but I don't really know how to achieve it with mongoDB

I'm using Mongoose by the way.

I hope this is clear.

Any idea?

Many thanks for your help! :)

Comment: tbh, i can't get it very well. You're not trying to modify the DB but the order to the output of a query, right?

Comment: @Minsky Yes sorry, not pretty clear. I'm trying to modify the documents order of the collection in the db : when a user modify the order of the list (front) and submit it, I want to re-organize the documents according to the user update. 
Do you get it?

Comment: I see. What of `db.coll.aggregate([ {$addFields:{"fieldname":userInput}} ])`. Of course, you need to target the document, or this will overwrite the full collection.

Comment: @Minsky I'm not sure to understand the solution. It's not sorting the db acccording to the user input?

Comment: @Minsky The user can change the position item in the UI. So the position (of the item, which is the item) should be updated in the collection

Comment: I'm not very good at F-end. But if the user receives `a:[1,2,3]` and changes `a:[3,2,1]` and you want  `var update = [3,2,1]` , then:  `db.coll.aggregate([{$match:{_id:docId}}, {$addFields:{"fieldname": update}} ])` should work.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the point, will remove the comments in a couple of mins.

Comment: The user receive `a:[doc1, doc2, doc3]` and post `a:[doc3, doc2, doc1]` to the db. So the collection in db is initially sort like this `[doc1, doc2, doc3]` and should be sort like this after the user updates `[doc3, doc2, doc1]` is `aggregate` works on this usecase ?

Comment: Oh, my bad. It's sorting documents, not subdocuments. Not sure how to do it then...

Comment: @Minsky Is there a way to update multiple documents with different values? The solution could be send the current position (in the array) of each element and then update the field with the current position in the db

Comment: No, you can update multiple documents with single values.